# What is the unique value that android assigns to each application in server?

Tags: android

Not talking about UserID or signature because they are the numbers each android device assigns for the applications. What I mean is the "key" (like domain name for URL) that identifies application uniquely. I know one is the root package name, but Is there any key values that is assigned/stored by android server ?

Comment: take a look here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html is that what you want?

Comment: bit different @DeividiCavarzan, I dont need to access it or be able to access it. My point is, in URL we understand that "facebook.com" is the unique ID for facebook. For application  com.facebook.katana" is root package of facebook. But is there "any other keys or signatures" or values that android server stores, assigns for each application so they remain universal same.

Comment: Oh, got it! Actually I really don't know any other identifier besides package name.